# Javascript function for simple login system

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying around for a bit and starting to lose my patience. Why doesn't this work? It meant for an easy school project and that's why it doesn't have to be secure at all, just functional.

I've been awake for almost 24hrs and im sure that it's part of the reason why i cant get it to work :)

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputUsername">Användarnamn</label>
      <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ange användarnamn">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword">Lösenord</label>
      <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Ange lösenord">
    </div>
    <div class="loginButton">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="login(this.form);">Logga In</button>
    </div>
  </form>

    <script>
  function login(form){
    if(form.username.value == "test") && (form.password.value == "test"){
      self.location.href = "medlemmar.html";
      }
      else{
        alert("Felaktigt användarnamn eller lösenord");
        return false;
      }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: what's the error coming for you?

Comment: Its not much of an error. Just that nothing happens when i press the submit button.

Comment: So your JS console is not telling you anything? Can you add some `console.log`s to your code? Particularly for the `form` parameter?

Comment: Maybe i could start by trying it in a JS console. Right now im just writing it in the same way i write HTML. :P

Answer (score 2):

You are now submitting a form without an action defined for the form, so probably, it is just refreshing the page.

So one way to solve this would be by changing the type of the button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="login(this.form);">Logga In</button>
```

Furthermore you have an error with the parenthesis in your if statement:

```
if((form.username.value == "test") && (form.password.value == "test")){
```

If you fix that, it should work as desired:

```js
  function login(form){
    if((form.username.value == "test") && (form.password.value == "test")){
      self.location.href = "medlemmar.html";
      }
      else{
        alert("Felaktigt användarnamn eller lösenord");
        return false;
      }
  }
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputUsername">Användarnamn</label>
      <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ange användarnamn">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputPassword">Lösenord</label>
      <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Ange lösenord">
    </div>
    <div class="loginButton">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="login(this.form);">Logga In</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Well... It was as easy as i expected it to be. I tried changing the button type before without any results, it was probably the paranthesis. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the button type to `button` instead of `submit`.

I did not try it but i guess that your form always does a submit without getting to a evaluate your login-function. Changing the type will prevent that.

Another way would be to maintain the submit type  and call `preventDefault()` function to avoid that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    enter code here

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var n = prompt("Enter your number here", "type your number here");

n = parselnt(n);

if (NaN(n))

{alert("plese enter number");}

else if (n==0)

alert{("The number is zero");}

else if (n%2)

{alert("the number is odd");}

else

{alert("the number is even");}

</script>

</head>


</body><body>
</html>

122
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>

<script language="javascript">
function checke(form)
{
if (form.user.value== "Admin" && form.psrd.value=="Admin")

{
alert("login is sucesfull")
}
else
{
alert("Invalid user id")
}
}
</script>
<body>
<table height="10" width="10" border="1px">
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="user">
</td>
<td>
<input type="password" maxlength="8" name="psrd" >
</td>
</tr>
<table>
</body>
</html>
```